# Python list extend, append every extend value with new line

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

Please help, I am using extend list to append multiple values to list.

I need to extend to list as a new line for every extend.

```
>>> list1 = []
>>> list1 = (['Para','op','qa', 'reason'])
>>> list1.extend(['Power','pass','ok', 'NA'])
>>> print list1
['Para', 'op', 'qa', 'reason', 'Power', 'pass', 'ok', 'NA']
```

I need to provide this list to csv and It has to print like two lines.

```
Para, op, qa, reason
Power, pass, ok, NA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanted separate lists, make them separate. Don't use `list.extend()`, use *appending*:

```
list1 = [['Para','op','qa', 'reason']]  # brackets, creating a list with a list
list1.append(['Power','pass','ok', 'NA'])
```

Now `list1` is a list with two objects, each itself a list:

```
>>> list1
[['Para', 'op', 'qa', 'reason'], ['Power', 'pass', 'ok', 'NA']]
```

If you are using the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to write out your CSV file, use the [`csvwriter.writerows()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) to write each row into a separate line:

```
>>> import csv
>>> import sys
>>> writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
>>> writer.writerows(list1)
Para,op,qa,reason
Power,pass,ok,NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Your desired result, list1, should be a list of two elements, that each one of them is a list by itself.

```
list1 = ['Para','op','qa', 'reason']
# wrapping list1 with [] crates a new list which its first element is the original list1.
# In your case, this action gives a list of lines with only one single line
# Only after that I can add a new list of lines that contains another single line
list1 = [list1] + [['Power','pass','ok', 'NA']]
print (list1)
```